# Check for word in table field MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a column with field ids
ids contains value like

```
1,2,3,4,....
```

Now I want to check an Id=4 in ids field

Comment: Poor DB design you need to normalize it, in the mean while checkout `find_in_set`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find_in_set`

```
select * from your_table
where find_in_set(4, ids) > 0
```

But actually you should rather change your table design. Never store multiple values in a single column.

Answer (score 0):

You can also used array for Checking it. but the stracture of the table should have to changed it would be good.